# Who did name Surah al-Isra as Bani-Israel? (As the other name of Al-Isra)?

Tags: naming, surah, surat-al-isra

The seventeenth Surah of the Holy Qur’an is famous as two names. Actually, one of its names is Al-Isra and the other name is well-known as Bani-Israel. I've got 2 queries:

1. Which one is the main name of this Surah?
2. Who named it as Bani-Israel? (As it is famous as Bani-Israel as
   well)

Comment: have a look at http://www.dewdropsweb.com/names-of-surahs/ for some background.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from [Soorat al-Isra’ is also called Soorat Bani Isra’eel](https://islamqa.info/en/163112) (read this full link for better understanding and full details.):

***Soorat al-Isra’ is called Soorat Bani Israa’eel in two saheeh mawqoof hadeeths***, in which it is the words of the Sahaabah (may Allah be pleased with them): 
The **first hadeeth** was narrated from ‘Abd-Allah ibn Mas‘ood (may Allah be pleased with him), who said concerning **(the soorahs) Bani Israa’eel, al-Kahf, Maryam, Ta-Ha and al-Anbiya’**: They are among the best and earliest and they are among the first I received.
Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 4994 
The **second hadeeth** was narrated from ‘Aa’ishah (may Allah be pleased with her) who said: The Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) used not to sleep **until he had recited Bani Israa’eel and al-Zumar**. Narrated by al-Tirmidhi, 3402, who said: It is a hasan hadeeth. It was also classed as hasan by al-Haafiz Ibn Hajar in Nataa’ij al-Afkaar, 3/65; and it was classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in Saheeh al-Tirmidhi. 
The scholars said that this soorah was better known by the name Soorat Bani Isra’eel at the time of the Sahaabah and Taabi’een

I don't think I can add anything or explain anything else.

I hope this answers the question.

Also read [Are the names of the surahs a matter of tawqeef?](https://islamqa.info/en/131664)

### Allah knows best

Comment: @DearMartyrSheikhNimr-Al-Nimr I think you are not satisfied yet, i you are than mark this as an answer, otherwise let me know what part of question is not answered. thankyou.